# How to tell that a test case (TFS work item) had been tested?

Tags: testing, tfs, testcase

I don't see in the test case work item status and reason anything to say "tested successfully"

- Design status is for when the test case is being written
- Ready status is for when the test case is ready to be tested
- Closed status has reasons saying the test case is "not to test" (deprecated, different, duplicated)

So how can we mark a test case as "successfully tested"?

It does not seem right that the tester does not have to attest that the case has been tested with success.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I did not have the chance to test your answer yet, just came back from vacation, i will check it within few days

Comment: Hi Jonathan Sure, kindly check it when you are free. Looking forward to hear your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

There is an "Outcome" field that will show pass, failed ect.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is **no such kind of build-in state** in Test Case work item. However, you could create your own customized work item state.

[image]

More details please take a look at this tutorial-- [Add a workflow stateAdd a workflow state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops#add-a-workflow-state)

> If you have latest version of tfs on web test hub you should select
>   several test cases and update the state (screens from Azure DevOps
>   Service):

[image]

Set new value for the State field

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're confusing Test Case with Test Result.  A test as defined by a Test Case can be run multiple times to obtain many Test Results.  This may not be very useful if the test is only getting run once, although it certainly still works; it is more useful when the test is being run multiple times, e.g. regression tests.

Also, if I may, your initial premise re: the different states a stock Test Case may be in is not correct.  Per [How workflow states and state categories are used in Backlogs and Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories), section [State categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories#state-categories),

- Design status is for when a test case is proposed, i.e. we should come up with a plan to test this case
- Ready status is for when a test case is in progress, i.e. we are implementing the the test plan
- Closed is for when a test case is completed, i.e. we have the plan

That said, I don't see why you couldn't use your above breakdown if it makes more sense for your team.  But either way, the notion of "tested successfully" still belongs to the realm of the Test Result.  Hope this helps to clarify things.